# Jquery - Animate Height Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, iframe, height

I have script that changes the hieght of an iframe based on the contents.  The script itself is work great, I am just wondering if there is a way to animate the height changes so that it is not so clunky when the iframe goes from 200px to 1000px?  This is my code so far, it works fine, i just need to add animation to it.  Thank you for the help.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    $("iframe.flexht").each(function() {
        $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("html").height() );
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: `$(this).animate({height : $(this).contents().find("html").height() }, speed);`

Answer (score 1):

This example is taken from http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$( "#book" ).animate({
  opacity: 0.25,
  left: "+=50",
  height: "toggle"
}, 5000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

Basically instead of setting the height directly you pass the animate function the value it should be. The animate function will then internally call the requestAnimationFrame function in order to change the value over time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

The second parameter given (5000) is the amount of time it will animate in milliseconds. So 5000 will last 5 seconds. This parameter is optional.

You can tell the animate function to animate differently by giving it an easing string. Not all easings are supported in jQuery but you can try a few listed here: http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Lastly, the empty function in the example is a function that will be called when the animation finishes. This parameter is also optional.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a "setInterval" it's a little heavier, because it's always checking something.

Did you try with css?... What if you put a transition to the .flexht class?

```
.flexht{
  -moz-transition:all 1s;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
  transition:all 1s;
}
```

Sorry, I don't know how your HTML looks like. But in my experience, this works.